# Event listener not applying

Tags: javascript, django, addeventlistener

I am trying to apply an on click event listener to buttons that are generated through django templating. My JavaScript file is linked up properly as if I do a standard console log it logs fine but the event listener loop doesn't seem to be doing anything.

***The for loop applying the event listener to each element with the class update-cart***

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')


for (var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++){
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'action:', action)
    })
}
```

***The buttons with the dataset attributes and update-cart class***

```
<button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-primary update-cart">Add To Cart</button>
```

***My JavaScript file linked in the scripts which is included before the end of the Body tag***

```
{% load static %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that after the innerHTML of a element has been updated, hidden properties of the elements inside will be removed. So it would be better if you run the loop inside the Window LoadEvent.

Comment: Thank you, I added a document ready function and it works fine